# Bach BWV 817: how do you realize this ornament, bars 10, 18

Tags: ornaments

How do you realize this ornament with the big tailhook at the end?
The editorial contains a cheat sheet but not this particular
ornament.

Bach BWV 817 Sarabande (Henle): bars 10, 18

[image: Bach BWV 817 sarabande from bar 10]

[image: Bach BVW 817 sarabande from bar 15]

Comment: Related [question](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/108865/2600).

Answer (score 1):

This ornament is to be played by filling up the interval, so an alternative notation would be

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The way I've most often heard this performed is as a rolled chord in which some of the "in between" notes are included along the way. So, for example, the chord in measure 10 might be performed something like:

[image: Sample realization]

The rhythms are not intended to be accurate — just an illustration of the order in which the notes might be executed.

This interpretation is backed up by the fingering in measure 18, which suggests that the C# be played with the thumb, the E with finger 2, and then a run of 2-3-4 up to the G#.

Glenn Gould performs measure 18 in this way, although in measure 10 he puts the "run" at the beginning (i.e., bottom) of the chord.